# How to create a custom record action button inside a List component with React-Admin?

Tags: react-admin

I'm a totally newbie with React and React-Admin. IMHO, I'm trying to achieve something simple that many people must have already done but I cannot find any kind of tutorial anywhere.

I'd like to add another button to the list of action buttons (show/edit) within each row in a `<List>` component. This button would archive the record.

[image: List of users with 4 action buttons]

My last try looks like the code below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Datagrid,
  EmailField,
  List,
  TextField,
  ShowButton,
  EditButton,
  DeleteButton,
  CloneButton,
} from 'react-admin';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ArchiveIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Archive';

const useRowActionToolbarStyles = makeStyles({
    toolbar: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        float: 'right',
        width: '160px',
        marginTop: -1,
        marginBottom: -1,
    },
    icon_action_button: {
      minWidth: '40px;'
    },
});

const ArchiveButton = props => {
  const transform = data => ({
    ...data,
    archived: true
  });

  return <CloneButton {...props} transform={transform} />;
}


const RowActionToolbar = (props) => {
  const classes = useRowActionToolbarStyles();
  return (
      <div className={classes.toolbar}>
        <ShowButton label="" basePath={props.basePath} record={props.record} className={classes.icon_action_button}/>
        <EditButton label="" basePath={props.basePath} record={props.record} className={classes.icon_action_button}/>
        <ArchiveButton {...props} basePath={props.basePath} label="" icon={<ArchiveIcon/>} record={props.record} className={classes.icon_action_button} />
        <DeleteButton basePath={props.basePath} label="" record={props.record} className={classes.icon_action_button}/>
      </div>
  );
};

export const UserList = props => {
  return (
    <List
      {...props}
      sort={{ field: 'first_name', order: 'ASC' }}
    >
      <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="first_name"/>
        <TextField source="last_name"/>
        <EmailField source="email"/>
        <RowActionToolbar/>
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  )
};
```

Obviously, this code does not work because the `<CloneButton>` component get rid of the `id` the record. Moreover, except if I did something wrong - which is totally possible -, it makes a `GET` request to a `create` endpoint.
I'm using different routes in my `dataProvider` (The back end is using Django and Django rest framework). I want to send a `PATCH` to the detail endpoint, like the `<Edit>` component does.

I also tried with a `<SaveButton>`, but it fails too.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
> at useSaveContext (SaveContext.js:23)

I guess the `<SaveButton>` must be within a `<SimpleForm>`?

I'd like the save behaviour of the `<DeleteButton>`, i.e. update the record from the list, display the notification that the record has been archived (with the Undo link), send the request to the back end, refresh the list.

Any guidance, directions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this is a full answer, but felt like more than a comment...

You are trying to archive the existing record, not create a whole new record, right? CloneButton is supposed to be used to create  a new record with a new ID (which is why your ID is going away), so you don't want to us it here. **note that I've never used CloneButton. it is not fully documented so I could be wrong about its use.**

I am thinking that you should use the useRecordContext hook within your Archive button to pull in all of the record's data, including the id; read this little section: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Architecture.html#context-pull-dont-push

And I don't think transform is what you're looking for here. You will need to use one of the dataProvider hooks, i'm assuming useUpdate: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#useupdate

Comment: You are totally right, I just wanted to test the behaviour with `transform` and the `CloneButton`. 
`useUpdate` was the way to go. Thank you. I still had a tiny issue. The row stayed there until the back-end response came in. To fix that, I extended the Datagrid component to only display data that would match filters.

Answer (score 0):

//first create component

```
const MyButton = (props: any) => {
const [sendEmailLoading, setSendEmailLoading] = 
React.useState<boolean>(false);
const record = useRecordContext(props);

const sendEmail = (id: Identifier) => {
  setSendEmailLoading(true)
  dataProvider.sendEmail(
    "notifications", { id: id })
    .then(({ data }: any) => {
      if (data && data.status == "success")
        notify('Email send success', { type: 'success' });
      setSendEmailLoading(false);
      refresh();
    });
 };
 return (
  <ButtonMUI color='primary' size="small" onClick={() => { 
 sendEmail(record.id) }}>
    {
      !record.publish &&(
      !sendEmailLoading ? (
        translate('resources.notifications.buttons.send')
      ) : (
        <CircularProgress size={25} thickness={2} />
      )
      )
    }
  </ButtonMUI>
 )
 }
```

//and second add to datagrid list

```
         <Datagrid>
        <NumberField source="id" />
        <TextFieldRA source="subject" />
        <DateField source="date" />
        <BooleanField source="publish" />
        {/* <EditButton /> */}
        <ShowButton />
        <MyButton />
      </Datagrid>
```